# Нет реакции на нажатие кнопки

Tags: java, android, button

Нету реакции на нажатие кнопки. Логи молчат.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button Button;
    TextView textView;
    private static final String TAG = "Log";
    @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }

    View.OnClickListener oclButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int seconds = 2;
            Log.d(TAG, "нажата кнопка");
                CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(seconds * 1000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        textView.setText("Seconds:" + (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        textView.setText("Готово!");

                    }
                };Button.setOnClickListener(oclButton);
            }



    };


}
```

В чём ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас плохо отформатирован код и в нём сложно разобраться но вы точно не там повесили созданный вами слушатель нажатий. Вы его повесили на кнопку внутри самого слушателя. Т.е. пока слушатель не будет вызван слушатель не будет назначен. Т.е. это никогда не произойдёт. Вам надо перенести строку

> Button.setOnClickListener(oclButton);

Сразу после инициализации самой кнопки, т.е. после строки

> Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

---

Также вам нужно обязательно соблюдать конвенции и не именовать переменные с большой буквы